# exacttarget: subscriber is missing required attribute

Tags: soap-api, marketing-cloud, email-template, .net

I have created template in Exact Target account. Added below attribute data in template.

```
City Name : %%CityName%%
 State Name : %%StateName%%

 From the code, I added below code in SOAP API (using .NET)

 Subscriber newSub = new Subscriber();
 newSub.EmailAddress = "XXXXX";
 newSub.SubscriberKey = "XXXXX";

 newSub.Attributes[0] = new etAPI.Attribute();
 newSub.Attributes[0].Name = "ExpDate";
 newSub.Attributes[0].Value = "02/31/2014";

 newSub.Attributes[1] = new etAPI.Attribute();
 newSub.Attributes[1].Name = "StateName";
 newSub.Attributes[1].Value = "VA";
```

I am getting below response from ExactTarget

> "ErrorDescription: Error Code: 10 - The subscriber is missing required
>   attribute value for CityName.Error Code:
>   TriggeredSendSubscriberProcessingError"

Can anybody suggest why I see this error ? Basically I need to achieve to send a email  using triggered send with dynamic data to the variables. It was successful if I remove above two attributes and got an email with no data of these variables in the email body.

Comment: It would be helpful to have more details and context. It is unclear what you are trying to do when you receive that error and where you are receiving the error from.

Comment: Updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it. It was wrong data is passed to the attribute. It is working fine now.

I had set ExpDate as 02/31/2014 which is invalid. After I corrected the date to 02/19/2014 it worked.

Comment: Could you clarify what it should have been compared to what you posted in your questions or how you debugged the problem ? Providing such info will help others running into similar problems. Else it may make more sense to remove the question.

Comment: I given ExpDate as 02/31/2014 which is invalid. After I corrected the date to 02/19/2014, then the issue is resolved.